# Как правильно написать переопределения переменных в swift?

Tags: swift, классы, переменные, переопределение

Как правильно написать код, чтоб он переопределял переменную?

Пишу так и мне компилятор показывает ошибку:

```
class x {
    var xx: String = "hot"
}

class s: x {
    var tt: Int = 9
    override
    var xx: String {
        return super.xx + "HIt \(tt)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе x у Вас хх - stored property.
В классе s Вы пытаетесь ее переопределить как computed property с одним get. Если хотите, необходимо дописать set, пример:

```
class s: x {
    var tt = 9
    private var _prefix = "Hit"
    override var xx: String {
        set { _prefix = newValue }
        get { return "\(_prefix) \(tt)" }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что такое stored property и computed property объясните простым деревенским языком

Comment: а что за операторы я просто новичок в swift  get{}  и  set{} ?

Comment: @LifeБедняка не умею особо объяснять. Stored property - обычная переменная. Можете присваивать ей значение и читать присвоенное значение. Computed property - присваивать значение этой переменной не можете, читать можете то что пропишете в return.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот эти видео там очень хорошо это описано(правда не помню в каком уроке) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNMFljBCOP8&list=PL6724Ll8v6UhOq6Otjw-rUPFsZVmoCLFm 
{set} {get}- так называемый set'ер и get'ер один устанавливает значение второй показывает значение.

Comment: А можно вообще не использовать return  ?